# Where does lightdm change $PATH

Tags: lightdm

I use lightdm on my Ubuntu 12.04 and I have the entry `/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm` in my `$PATH` if I login through lightdm. Now I'm cleaning my `$PATH` and I simply want to know where this entry gets added.

This entry doesn't appear if I login via terminal.

Comment: Can you post the contents of `~/.xinitrc`, if it exists?

Comment: It only contains commented `exec <session>` for `startx`. I guess `lightdm` doesn't need this.

Comment: Did I say `.xinitrc`? I'm very sorry, I was thinking of `.xsessionrc`, which is sourced when you log in graphically. There are also other related rc files which may run depending on the DE (`.gnomerc`, etc.). It could be in any of them. You could grep your home directory for any mention of this: `grep -R /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm ~/.[a-z]*`